# Dar orden a MenuStrip

Tags: sql, vb.net

tengo una duda, tengo un MenuStrip con varios elementos y queria saber si hay alguna forma de hacer que se siga un orden para entrar a cada elemento, me explico:

Quiero que primero entren a la pestaña de "lineas" y luego a la de "numero de parte" y al final "condiciones"

pero que no salten ese orden, hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

tengo este codigo (no son todos los elementos pero de esta manera los llamo):

```
Public frm_pteestampa As FormParteEstampada
Public frm_co As Form_CO

Public Sub abrir_CO()
    frm_co = New Form_CO
    frm_co.MdiParent = Me
    frm_co.Show()
End Sub
Public Sub abrir_Estampa()
    frm_pteestampa = New FormParteEstampada
    frm_pteestampa.MdiParent = Me
    frm_pteestampa.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub ParteEstampadaToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ParteEstampadaToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Me.abrir_Estampa()
End Sub
Private Sub CondicionesOperacionToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CondicionesOperacionToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Me.abrir_CO()
End Sub
```

Ojala y me puedan ayudar, gracias...

Comment: Para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver el código que tienes, en este caso como estas cargando los elementos en el `MenuStrip`. Te recomiendo echar un vistazo a [ask] y tambien [Sin código, es difícil ayudarte](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2875/)

Comment: Gracias por las recomendaciones Pikoh , ya gregue mi codigo ojala puedan ayudarme

Comment: Sigo sin entender muy bien lo que quieres hacer, pero por lanzar una suposicion..porque no tienes desactivas los items del toolstrip y les activas cuando se seleccione la opcion anterior?

Comment: Mira cada elemento del MenuStrip es una tabla, al llenar todas las tablas hago una consulta para mostrar varios datos de cada tabla. pero se debe de seguir un orden en el registro de las tablas para que se pueda hacer la consulta